# SSRS ReportBuilder crashed on me, now it won't re-open a report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I’ve been editing a report (ReportBuilder 3.0) and was playing about with the positioning for a legend entry on one of the charts.

It let me save the report, but when I ran it in IE it displayed an error in the chart placeholder.

When I went back to ReportBuilder to undo the changes, it crashed on me, and now when I try to reopen the report I get the following error and cannot open the report:

[image]

Can anyone advise a way to get the report to open again so that I can edit it please?

Comment: Try editing a COPY of the .rdl file using a text editor (I use Notepad++). You could then comment out / remove some of the XML lines that may be causing the error.

Comment: @MiguelH - many thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: @MiguelH - perfect, worked a treated. I was able to chop the offending chart out of the XML code (took a bit of finding - the script was compiled all over the place...), but it's saved me many hours of reproducing the report. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! Glad to see it worked!

Comment: @MiguelH - Please add your suggestion as an answer so we can vote it up and also it will be easier to find for the next person looking for a solution to the same issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3834961/jon295087 Could you mark the answer below as being the solution to your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing a COPY of the .rdl file using a text editor (I use Notepad++). You could then comment out / remove some of the XML lines that may be causing the error.